# How can I recombine factor levels based on a portion of their string variable?

Tags: r, string, datetime, dplyr, cumsum

I have some data that I split if the time difference between subsequent points is greater than some threshold and rename the ID where the split occurs

```
# prep the data
ID = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
DateTime = c("2014-09-25 08:39:45", "2014-09-25 08:39:48", "2014-09-25 08:40:44", "2014-09-25 09:04:00","2014-09-25 09:04:10", "2014-09-25 08:33:32", "2014-09-25 08:34:41", "2014-09-25 08:35:24", "2014-09-25 09:04:00", "2014-09-25 09:04:09")
df = data.frame(ID,DateTime, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, tz = "UTC")

# split if the time difference is greater than 100 and rename the IDs

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(timeDiff = c(NA, difftime(tail(DateTime, -1), head(DateTime, -1), units="sec"))) %>%
  mutate(newID = paste(ID, cumsum(!is.na(timeDiff) & timeDiff > 100),sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

After this I run some functions the data based on the newID column.

But I would like to stitch my data back together again after this. Thus, A_0, A_1 would be stuck back together as A and similarly for B.

I just need something that recognises the factor levels before the _ when I perform the stitch but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Maybe an easy way is to use `tidyr::separate`, something in the line of: `df %>% tidyr::separate(newID, into = c('ID', NA), sep = '_')`. That way you have your old ID back for grouping or wahtever you need.

Comment: The issue is my old ID column gets lost by the subsequent operations

Comment: Yeah, I supposed that. WIth separate you get your old ID back separating newID by '_', the first part will be ID and the second part you can give it a column or get rid of it as i did in the code with NA. `separate` will broke your newID in one or more columns, take a look at its help `?tidyr::separate`